# Using hyperref makes enumerate in tables not aligned

Tags: hyperref, enumerate

This is what I want to do:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}  
%\usepackage{hyperref} % without hyperref one line, with hyperref two lines
\begin{document}
Some text
\begin{minipage}[t]{10cm}
  \begin{enumerate}
  \item Some text
  \end{enumerate}
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

And works just fine, as expected:
[image]

But if I uncomment the line

```
\usepackage{hyperref}
```

I obtain
[image]

Have you any ideas on how to solve the problem?

UPDATE:

What should I do if I need hyperref functionality inside the enumerate?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To get PDF links working, `hyperref` needs to insert the link targets, which are implemented in TeX as "whatsits". These whatsits are not invisible to TeX's treatment of boxes. The enumerate environment gets a whatsit at the top of the first item. Now, the top alignment of the `minipage` refers to this whatsit instead of the base line of the first line.

Workaround: If this `enumerate` do not need "hyper" features, then they can be turned off temporarily via environment `NoHyper`:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}  
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
Some text
\begin{minipage}[t]{10cm}
  \begin{NoHyper}% <<<<<< HERE
    \begin{enumerate}
    \item Some text
    \end{enumerate}%
  \end{NoHyper}%   <<<<<< HERE
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: Heiko, while you were preparing your answer, I reduced the working example to a minimal one, to make the issue clearer. However, it didn't match your answer anymore, so I now also edited your answer (edit waiting for review). The first solution applies directly also to the new MWE, but the automatic  measuring (`\heightof`) in the second one yields a wrong height; for the moment I replaced it by a fixed value. Sorry for breaking your solution. Anyway, it shows that the second solution is quite fragile and does not carry over to similar contexts.

Comment: Ah, great, even the picture has been magically adapted! So everything now matches ...

Comment: @gernot Thanks for calling me a magician :-) (I got notified about the proposed editing and have recreated the image.)

Comment: Which tool chain do you use to obtain these high resolution images with transparent background? When I use gimp to crop the pdfs and save them as jpg, the resolution turns bad. Is there any documentation on tricks how to produce the material for this forum?

Comment: @gernot Never use JPEG for this kind of images, a lossless format (PNG) is much better. The images here are generated by ghostscript's device `pngalpha`.

Comment: I see... Thank you very much!
Instead, What should I do if i need "hyper" features? (besides manually moving the text)

Answer (score 0):

The explanation was given by Heiko Oberdiek. Here is a sort of work-around. I didn't try very hard to get vertical spacing "right" whatever that means, below the enumerate. I use `enumitem` package to kill via `parsep=0pt` the glue added on top of enumerate.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}  
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}
Some text
\raisebox{\ht\strutbox}{%\tracingmacros1
\begin{minipage}[t]{10cm}%
  \begin{enumerate}[parsep=0pt]
  \item \label{zoo}\strut Some text
  \item  Some text
  \item  Some text
  \item  Some text
  \item \label{foo}Some text
  \item  Some text
  \end{enumerate}
\strut
\end{minipage}\relax}

\vspace{-\baselineskip}

Next paragraph, see \ref{zoo}.

Next paragraph, see \ref{foo}.

%\showoutput
\end{document}
```

[image]