# Bad alignment with minipages, enumerate and doclicense

Tags: vertical-alignment, enumerate, minipage

I've noticed that the content of the `minipage` environments is not correctly aligned in the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{doclicense}

\begin{document}
    \begin{minipage}[t]{.5\linewidth}
        \begin{enumerate}
            \item foo;
        \end{enumerate}
    \end{minipage}
    \begin{minipage}[t]{.5\linewidth}
        \begin{enumerate}
            \item[] bar
        \end{enumerate}
    \end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

I would expect to get:

[image: Expected result]

But instead it is:

[image]

Either commenting `\usepackage{doclicense}` or using `\item bar` (without the square brackets) gets it fixed.
Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong? I could do without the `doclicense` package but would like to know what is causing this anyways.

Comment: The same issue can be reproduced by loading `\usepackage{hyperref}` instead of `doclicense` (`doclicense` loads `hyperref` automatically).

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/328904/using-hyperref-makes-enumerate-in-tables-not-aligned

Comment: @Ulrike Fischer I guess my question can be considered a duplicate then.

Answer (score 1):

It seems loading `enumitem` and specifying an emptylabel solves the problem:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{doclicense}

\begin{document}

    \begin{minipage}[t]{.5\linewidth}
        \begin{enumerate}
            \item foo;
        \end{enumerate}
    \end{minipage}
    \begin{minipage}[t]{.5\linewidth}

        \begin{enumerate}[label ={}]
            \item bar
        \end{enumerate}
    \end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I see. But it looks that my MWE was too minimal: I need to have have more `\item` elements with labels in the same `enumerate` environment.

Comment: You can close the enumerate and reopen another after the first, with specific parameters. This is very easy with `enumitem`.